# Delete only accessed files using find -amin -1 and not files created in the previous minute

Tags: linux

I need to delete every accessed file in the previous minute, every minute.
That is, to delete the files using the output of **`find . -amin -1`** command, and repeat that deletion again the next minute. But when, new files are added in that interval, the above find command also returns the newly created (not accessed) files in the output. I want to exclude those new files and prevent them from being deleted. How do I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

Well .. the machine does exactly what you're asking.
What you WANT is something slightly different, I believe.

```
find . -amin -2 -a -amin +1
```

Comment: This does exactly the opposite of what I want. It lists all the newly created files and ignores all the accessed files.

Comment: There you go ... @cosihak